# Cannot get values in 3rd level SubFormState

Tags: 8, forms, blocks, plugins

I have a block that embeds another plugins into itself and this includes configuration form. I can properly handle the form structure but when it comes to validation I am not able to access the values in the embedded plugin form validation handler. I was looking at the SubFormState and I tried to adjust the #parents of the provided form element but it didn't help. I know SubFormState is far from perfect but this should not be an issue.

This is my form:

```
// ...
$carousel_ajax = [
      'wrapper' => 'carousel-settings-ajax-wrapper',
      'callback' => [get_called_class(), 'selectCarouselAjaxFormRebuild']
    ];

    // No need for "#tree" option here since this form is already embedded.
    $form['carousel'] = [
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => $this->t('Carousel'),
      '#prefix' => '<div id="' . $carousel_ajax['wrapper'] . '">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>'
    ];

    $form['carousel']['plugin'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => $this->t('Use carousel'),
      '#options' => ['' => '- ' . $this->t('None') . ' -'] + $this->carouselManager->getList(),
      '#default_value' => $configuration['carousel']['plugin'],
      '#ajax' => $carousel_ajax + ['trigger_as' => ['name' => 'select_carousel_submit']],
    ];

    $form['carousel']['select_carousel_submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#name' => 'select_carousel_submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Select carousel'),
      '#submit' => [[$this, 'selectCarouselFormSubmit']],
      '#limit_validation_errors' => [['settings', 'carousel']],
      '#ajax' => $carousel_ajax,
      '#attributes' => [
        'class' => ['js-hide']
      ]
    ];

    $form['carousel']['settings'] = [];
    if (!empty($configuration['carousel']['plugin']) && $this->carouselManager->hasDefinition($configuration['carousel']['plugin'])) {
      $carousel_plugin = $this->carouselManager->createInstance($configuration['carousel']['plugin'], $configuration['carousel']['settings']);
      $form['carousel']['settings'] = $carousel_plugin->buildConfigurationForm(
        $form['carousel']['settings'],
        SubformState::createForSubform($form['carousel']['settings'], $form, $form_state)
      );
    } else {
      $form['carousel']['settings'] = [
        '#type' => 'value',
        '#value' => []
      ];
    }

    return $form;
```

This is the block form validation handler(I am experimenting with various structures and whatnot):

```
public function blockValidate($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    if ($form_state->hasValue(['carousel', 'plugin'])) {
      $carousel_plugin = $this->carouselManager->createInstance(
        $form_state->getValue(['carousel', 'plugin']),
        $form_state->getValue(['carousel', 'settings'])
      );
      //array_shift($form['settings']['carousel']['settings']['#parents']);
      $carousel_plugin->validateConfigurationForm(
        $form['settings']['carousel']['settings'],
        SubformState::createForSubform($form['settings']['carousel']['settings'], $form, $form_state)
      );
    }
  }
```

---

3rd level because the block itself is 2nd level being embedded in the `\Drupal\block\BlockForm::form`

Answer (score 3):

After quite some experimenting I came to a working solution.

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function blockValidate($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    if ($form_state->hasValue(['carousel', 'plugin'])) {
      $carousel_plugin = $this->carouselManager->createInstance(
        $form_state->getValue(['carousel', 'plugin']),
        $form_state->getValue(['carousel', 'settings'])
      );

      // We have to do some manual adjustments here since the SubFormState
      // is far from perfect.
      $element = $form['settings']['carousel']['settings'];
      array_shift($element['#parents']);

      $carousel_plugin->validateConfigurationForm(
        $element,
        SubformState::createForSubform($element, $form, $form_state)
      );
    }
```

So the embedded validation handler has to receive **altered** form element and the subformstate has to receive the original, intact, form.